# Change input number to money format when typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, numbers, currency

I have an input type text, and i want to change the number format when typing, here's the example format that i want :

> user type = 3445

and the input field auto format the input:

```
US 3.445,00
```

i've followed the example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yWTLk) , but it's for comma format

Comment: you need to have the input as type="text" since type="number" inputs will not support the other characters. Then you can do a function on the keyup to split the input into the portions, add the non-numeric characters. You will need to strip these characters out if you are using the value for calculations. Also note that even type="number" input values are strings - so need ot be parsed as numberss before calcuations on them

Comment: @gavgrif ok fix it, and updated my question

Comment: What's the ",00" at the end signify?

Comment: @jonmrich its just the decimal point which automatically added at the end of user input, for example if i type **1** it will be **1,00**